# Open CV Python Face Detection

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, rectangles, haar-classifier

I am looking it to using haar cascades for face detection, so I tried following the tutorial here:
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html

When I run it though, the image window populates, but the rectangles are not drawn. I checked over the code and everything makes sense to me or if maybe I was using a function that was obsolete, but everything seemed alright.

I am not sure why I cannot get this working. Any suggestions as to what might be wrong?
I am using Python 2.7.3.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('searchin2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.Rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
    for(ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
        cv2.Rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try `print 'faces:', len(faces)` to see how many faces it found.

Comment: @furas, faces: 0. So, I am guessing the classifier needs to be adjusted because I am using a frontal face image that should be detected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to run this script and I got `faces: 0` too.

So I try to find out where is the problem.
I found out that I have no XML files on my disk.
There is no info in tutorials that you have to download it seperately 
and where to get this files.

But I downloaded [OpenCV source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) ZIP file, I found `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` in this file and I put it directly in folder with script. Now I have `faces: 2` :)

But now I have also error:

```
cv2.Rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Rectangle'
```

I'm still working on it.

---

**EDIT:** It has to be lowercase - `rectangle` :) Now it works for me :)

[image]

oryginal image source: [wikimedia ?](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Arnold_Schwarzenegger_edit%28ws%29.jpg/528px-Arnold_Schwarzenegger_edit%28ws%29.jpg)